# How do you groupby a number of rows offset from the first occurence of a month in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to offset the groupby boundaries by some number of rows.

For example, given the following dates

```
-----
1/1
1/2
1/3
...
2/1
2/2
2/3
-----
```

I would like to get a group with [1/2, 1/3, ... ,2/1, 2/2] which would be an offset of 1.

To add to this, not all the dates are there. For example, given the following dates

```
-----
1/2
1/4
1/15
...
1/31
2/5
2/10
2/25
-----
```

I would like to get the group [1/4, 1/15, ... ,1/31, 2/5, 2/10] which would be an offset of 1.

To add to this, I require negative offsets to work too, so given these dates

```
-----
1/2
1/4
1/15
1/31
2/5
2/10
2/25
2/26
2/28
-----
```

I would like to get the group [1/4, 1/15, 1/31, 2/5, 2/10, 2/25] which would be an offset of -3.

Is there a way to do this with groupby?

The following puts the boundaries of the groups at the first of the month, but I can not figure out how to move the boundaries by rows.

```py
df.groupby([df["<DATE_GROUP>"].dt.year, df["<DATE_GROUP>"].dt.month], as_index=False)
```

The `.nth()` method does not work because it only returns one member from each group, and I require that all the groups be in tact for processing.

TL;DR: I am trying to offset the groupby boundaries by some number of rows.

Comment: I had to fix some mistakes

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _negative_ offset: That would be an extension instead of a restriction, following your logic. But the example doesn't show that? Imho your examples also don't reflect the grouping that your are doing in the last code block? What is your basic grouping?

Comment: To answer your question, it is like ```nth(-3)```. I think I may have a solution using nth to make a mask of booleans for groupby.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way to do this, but it involves two groupby operations.

The idea is to groupby month and then use the `nth()` method to create a mask for a second groupby. The following code will return the group in the last example in my post.

```
df_monthly = df.groupby([df["<DATE_GROUP>"].dt.year, df["<DATE_GROUP>"].dt.month], as_index=False)

mask = df["<DATE_GROUP>"].isin(df_monthly.nth(-3)["<DATE_GROUP>"]).cumsum()

df.groupby(mask, as_index=False)
```